# How to solve a post request error on django

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I encountered certain post request error on django. When I click on the **form submit button** the error pops up stating that django can't find the page I'm asking for. Please I want to know where I'm getting it wrong because I'm still a beginner in django.

```
def account_register(request):
 #   if request.user.is_authenticated:
 #       return redirect('account:dashboard')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        registerForm = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if registerForm.is_valid():
            user = registerForm.save(commit=False)
            user.email = registerForm.cleaned_data['email']
            user.set_password(registerForm.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Activate your Account'
            message = render_to_string('account/registration/account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            user.email_user(subject=subject, message=message)
            return HttpResponse('registered succesfully and activation sent')
    else:
        registerForm = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'account/registration/register.html', {'form': registerForm})
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('account/register', views.account_register, name='register'),
    path('activate/<slug:uidb64>/<slug:token>)/', views.account_activate, name='activate')
]
```

urls.py(main django app)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('account.urls', namespace='account')),
]
```

views.py

```
def account_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        registerForm = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if registerForm.is_valid():
            user = registerForm.save(commit=False)
            user.email = registerForm.cleaned_data['email']
            user.set_password(registerForm.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Activate your Account'
            message = render_to_string('account/registration/account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            user.email_user(subject=subject, message=message)
            return HttpResponse('registered succesfully and activation sent')
    else:
        registerForm = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'account/registration/register.html', {'form': registerForm})
```

Template

```
account_activation_email.html
{% autoescape off %}
Hi {{ user.user_name }},

Your account has successfully created

http://{{ domain }}{% url 'account:activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

account/registration/register.html

```
<form class="account-form p-4 rounded col-lg-10 mx-auto" action="." method="post">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {% if form.errors %}
                                <p>Please correct the following errors:</p>
                                {% for field in form %}
                                {% if field.errors %}
                                <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
                                    {{ field.label }}: {{ field.errors|striptags }}
                                </div>
                                {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                                {% endif %}

                                <label>{{ form.user_name.label }}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.user_name }}
                                <label>{{ form.email.label}}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.email }}
                                <label>{{ form.password.label}}<span class="text-muted mb-4">
                                        </span></label>
                                 <small class="form-text text-muted mb-4 small">
                                    At least 8 characters and 1 digit
                                </small>
                                {{ form.password }}
                                <label>{{ form.password2.label}}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.password2 }}
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block py-2 mb-4 mt-5 fw500 w-100" type="submit">Register</button>
                                <p class="text-center">
                                    <a>Already have an account?</a>
                                </p>
                            </form>
```

Comment: Update the question to include the html template contents and also the Django error page.

Comment: I have added the template but having some challenge in uploading the image. However, when I click on the submit button of the registration form it ought to sent a HttpResponse if it's successful just as it's specified in views.py. In the project, Django goes through the urls and tells me that `The current path, account/, didn’t match any of these` (that is, any of the urls I specified in urls.py, but I'm supposed to get a HttpResponse sent back to the browser if the registration is successful instead of rendering a template)

Comment: Can you please show your `account/registration/register.html` template?

Comment: @GwynBleidD2, I have added the register template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url pattern is like:

```
'account/register'
```

Next your form tag has the action attribute as:

```
action="."
```

What does an action attribute `.` mean? Well it means use the current directory as the action url for this form. What is the current directory here? Well since your url is `/account/register` and it has no trailing slash, one can say `register` is a file and `/account/` is the current directory, which is where your form gets submitted and you get an error.

Simple fix is add a trailing slash to the url pattern:

```
path('account/register/', views.account_register, name='register'),
```

Plus also forego the action attribute on the form tag since that means the action url is the current page (and not the current directory):

```
<form class="account-form p-4 rounded col-lg-10 mx-auto" method="post">
```